# Converting function text return to string

Tags: jquery

I have a function that validates login:

```
var checkLogin = async (email, pass, captcha) => {

    alert('Checking login')

    return $.ajax("/users/ajax_login", {
    data: {
        email: email,
        pass: pass,
        captcha: captcha 
        }, 
      }).done((response) => {
        console.log('Done ', response)
      }).fail(error => {
        console.log('Error ', error)
      })
        .always(response => {
       console.log('always ', response)
      }).then(msg => {
        console.log('login response: ' + msg);
        return msg;

      })    
}
```

It returns a string that tells me if the login was successful.
When I check the response, it seems its an Object, not a string, which means I cannot parse it correctly (eg, check if the response is a string such as `good`).

So this code:

```
var loginResponse = checkLogin(email, pass, captcha );
loginResponse = loginResponse.toString();
console.log('first 4 chars: ' + loginResponse.substring(0,4));
```

will write `[obj` to the console.

How would I go about correctly converting the response to a string I can parse?

Thanks

Comment: We would need to see the logic within `checkLogin()` in order to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I check the response, it seems its an Object not a string, which means i cannot parse it correctly

Correct, `async` functions always return Promise objects, which are used to observe the result of an asynchronous operation.

To use the string, you need to consume the promise. There are two ways:

1. Using its `then` and `catch` methods:

   ```
   checkLogin(/*...*/)
   .then(result => {
       // Use `result` here, presumably it's a string if `checkLogin`'s docs say it will be
   })
   .catch(error => {
       // Handle or report `error` here, something went wrong in `checkLogin`'s asynchronous processing
   });
   ```

   You can leave off the `catch` if you're returning the promise to the calling function (which should handle errors).
2. Using `await` (inside an `async` function):

   ```
   try {
       const result = await checkLogin(/*...*/);
       // Use `result` here, presumably it's a string if `checkLogin`'s docs say it will be
   } catch (e {
       // Handle or report `error` here, something went wrong in `checkLogin`'s asynchronous processing
   }
   ```

   You can leave off the `catch` if you want to leave handling errors to the calling function.